# How to center align a flexbox container?

Tags: css, html, alignment, flexbox

I successfully created a responsive grid as the snippet shows.

At the moment, I see the boxes aligned to the left.

How can I put the container in the center of the page without having to use padding?

I tried using `margin:auto` but it did not work.

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
.box{
    width:100%;
    max-width:30%;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:5px;
}
@media only screen and ( max-width:768px ){ 
    .box{
        width:100%;
        max-width:40%;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>This is the first box</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci voluptates, aut totam eaque possimus molestiae atque odio vero optio porro magni, quis culpa ea. Perferendis, neque, enim. Rem, quia, quisquam.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cx1svoky/1/).

Comment: add width to your container class

Comment: To use `margin:auto` your container must have `width`.

Comment: I added a width of 100% in the container but it had no effect.  
here my snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/cx1svoky/3/

Comment: give width in px, like 500px

Comment: @chirag. I actually tried 1000px but it doesn't really center.

Answer (score 27):

Use `justify-content: center;` instead of `margin: auto;`:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 30%;
   border: 1px solid red;
   margin: 5px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
  .box {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

See [`justifiy-content` docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

[Updated JS Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/cx1svoky/4/)

Comment: It centers perfectly. But I just noticed that the fourth box does not float to the left now.The idea is to have boxes being added from left to write as more articles come. For instance if I have 7 boxes,the seventh box should flow to the left and not  to the  center.
Hope I made some sense.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Then you can use `margin: 0 auto;` with a fixed width, for example `width: 800px;`. See [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cx1svoky/9/).

Comment: It doesn't really center like I mentioned in other comments previously. But  well,it seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 3):

just add this line to your original code:

```
.container{
  width: 100%
}
```

and put the `div` box into another `div` that have a `margin: auto;`

if you need 2 boxes in the same line add `display: inline-table;` to the `box` class

Comment: Mind sending a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin:0px auto;` with a `width`.

For example:

```
.container{

display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
text-align:center;
margin:0px auto;
width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to have boxes being added from left to right, and the first box on the next row to be left aligned, you can use:`

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cx1svoky/29/)

Comment: this does not center the flexbox container though